# Form1_KeyDown calling button1_Click

Tags: c#, click, keydown

I have such piece of code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Do something...
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.A) {
            // Call button1_Click.
        }
    }
```

How do I manage to call the Click event? What should I write instead of

```
            // Call button1_Click.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use methods instead of faking events. Events should not be called but are triggered. So extract the relevant code in `button1_Click` and add it to a new method with a meaningful name. Then call this method from `button1_Click` and from `Form1_KeyDown`.

Comment: You should never put functional code into an event.  Make a method of what you want to reuse and call it from both places.

Comment: button1_Click(sender, null) will probably work if you don't use 'e'

Comment: Do you want to mimic the mouse click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are meant to be triggered not called. So you can trigger the event in your `Form1_KeyDown` event by performing the button click. I mean

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.A) {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the button click event handler is just a method, you could just do:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.A) {
        button1_Click(this, e);
    }
}
```

However, it's often a better idea to move the *logic* into a separate method, and call it from both locations.  By refactoring the logic within `button1_Click` into it's own method, you make it clear that you're calling that logic from either set of event handlers.